# Including model functions in controller in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to put all my PHP functions in a separate file. I'm using `require` to include them in the controller file but I get errors with undefined variables in the view file.
For example:

A function stored in a file 'functions.php' validating my contact form (for the sake of clarity reduced here to validating only one field):

```
function validateContactForm()
{
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $name_error = 'Name is required.';
    } else {
        $name = ($_POST['name'];
        if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/", $name)) {
            $name_error = 'Enter a valid name.';
        }
    }               
}
```

In my controller I put this `require 'functions.php';`.

My view file which gives undefined variable errors. It's just an HTML file with PHP code echoing validation messages.

```
<form 
name="contact" 
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" 
method="post">

<label 
for="name" 
id="name-form">
Name:
</label>
    <span id="name-error">
    <?php echo $name_error; ?></span>
</form>
```

It all works great when I put the PHP code without enclosing it in a function on top of the view file. I've tried to `return $name` in the function, I've tried `require_once` and also I used `$name` as an argument in the function:  `validateContactForm($name)` .

I have followed some simple tutorials where `return` statement is supposed to be enough but obviously I'm missing something.

Looks like my view file can't access the variables in the function `validateContactForm()`.

Comment: Can you show your effort with `return`? It's not enough to make the function return a value - you need to store that value in a variable in order to use it, e.g. `$var = functionThatReturnsSomething();` or perhaps directly output it like `echo functionThatReturnsSomething();`. Depends on whether you're going to use it in multiple places or in a single place.

Comment: Use classes and not functions; use class attributes and not variables; use spl autoloaders and not require statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem:

The variables in your `functions.php` file have file-scope. You may access them with the use of `global` or `$GLOBALS` or the `use` keyword on anonymous functions.

I recommend, that you use classes to store your functions.
**Please note, that it is not good practice to use globals in the first place.**

### Possible solutions:

Anyway, you could use any one of these options below*:
*This list of options may not be complete.

---

**./lib.php**

```php
<?php

// variables have file-scope, can`t be used directly via require
$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;

// anonymous functions can use the keyword `use` to access the variable
$callFoo = function() use ($foo) {
    echo $foo;
};

// with normal functions, we use the global keyword to get the variable 
function callBar() {
    global $bar;
    echo $bar;
}

// alternative to the one above ...
function callBarAlternative() {
    echo $GLOBALS['bar'];
}

// working with classes:
class Foo {
    public $publicFoo = 3;
    private $privateFoo = 4;

    function fooMethod() {
        echo $this->privateFoo;
    }
}
```

**./view.php**

```php
<?php

require "lib.php";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="text/html" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $callFoo();
        callBar();
        callBarAlternative();
        $foo = new Foo();
        echo $foo->publicFoo;
        $foo->fooMethod();
        echo $GLOBALS['bar'];
        global $bar;
        echo $bar;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The output for these calls will be: `1223422`

Answer (score 1):

The PHP variables inside a function have a local scope and so they are not visible outside. Use the "global" keyword to indicate that the variable is global.

```
function validateContactForm()
{
    global $name_error, $name;
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $name_error = 'Name is required.';
    } else {
        $name = ($_POST['name'];
        if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/", $name)) {
            $name_error = 'Enter a valid name.';
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: Please note that using globals should be considered as a last resort. If a value really isn't needed all across your application at all times, it has no business of being global. Globals can be changed *anywhere* in the code, which makes debugging that much harder.

Answer (score 0):

The most right way for me to do this looks like this (based on the general code logic):

```
/**
 * @param Array $POST
 */
function validateContactForm($POST){
    
    if( empty($POST['name']) ){
         throw new Exception('Name is required');
    }

    if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/", $POST['name'])) {
        throw new Exception('Enter a valid name');
    }

}
```

Then in the view you can do:

```
try {
     validateContactForm($_POST);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // show the error to the user somehow..
}
```

By this way, you can expand the logic in the function however you wish later and not be able to change code elsewhere. You can also check & validate multiple $_POST data.

Comment: Please avoid using exceptions for simple validation. Wrong user input is not exceptional and there is no need to introduce a complex construct such as an exception (with a full stack trace and everything) just to convey a message to the user.

Comment: @El_Vanja I am quite disagree with that, but ok different opinions are useful.